# accessing "jquery.sumoselect" in angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sumoselect.js

I need to access "jquery.sumoselect" module inside my AngularJS component. I tried different haphazard stuff but no luck so far.

Since I'm not an expert in front-end development so any help for me would be appreciated.

Comment: It's globally available so you can access it everywhere.

Comment: Hmm. Indeed I tried to follow http://jameshill.io/articles/angular-third-party-injection-pattern/ example but it doesn't work in my case :(